# Why are high-rep users allowed to delete their own questions without approval?

Tags: discussion

I just spent half an hour writing up a detailed response to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531548/postback-from-itemtemplate-link/), only to have the author delete it seconds later. I posted a followup and a moderator re-opened the original, only to have the poster close it again. Questions and answers are for community benefit, I don't see why he should be able to wipe his question when it has a good response. This is very demotivating and I'm sure anyone else who has had this happen is much less likely to spend their time and thought into answering a question. This is a contributing factor to the "[fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)" problem, and promotes two-line answers that don't really answer anything.

Comment: There's no difference between high-rep and any other non-moderator user. Anyone can delete their question if it isn't locked and doesn't have upvoted answers.

Comment: How is this related to the FGITW problem?

Comment: Just flag a moderator again note the history and leave it to them. The last thing you want to do is engage the OP in an argument.

Comment: @Mysticial I tried deleting a tumbleweed question of mine with no answers nor comments for 2 months and it told me to contact a monderator instead. Animuson, I'd now rather just drop a line or two outlining the problem rather than actually taking time to explain it.

Comment: @Zerkey Which question was that?